# Where do I find app data in Android

Tags: android, file

My goal is to save data from app in a text file for further analysis. I used the exact code as given [here](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/06/android-internal-external-storage.html) for saving data:

The data is stored and retrieved according to the app, but I am not able to find MySampleFile.txt (even using the search functionality) on the phone.

I can't find it in `Android -> data -> com.*.*.` I have a Samsung Galaxy S3. Is anything different in this phone?

Should I make any modifications in the phone?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To see `data`, you phone must be `root`. Samsung Galaxy S3 is not a root from vendor, you need to root your phone to access internal memory/storage, you can only access external memory/storage in your phone i.e. sdcard

But, i would suggest you to use `Emulator` rather root your phone.

Here, are some links about what is rooting, you can go through these:

http://gizmodo.com/5982287/reasons-to-root-your-android-device
http://lifehacker.com/5789397/the-always-up+to+date-guide-to-rooting-any-android-phone
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_rooting

But again I would suggest to use Emulator unless you are not expert enough to root and Install firmwares again when you don't want your phone root.

Please use `Emulator` to see `data->com.package`

From Windows Menu->ShowView->Others->android->fileExplorer you can see the file in your device

Specify permission in AndroidManifest.xml:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Comment: But if I go to Android->data, I find folders like com.amazon.kindle and com.imangi.templerun and so on. I'm guessing they're folders for app data. I need to do something similar for my com.example.app.

Comment: you can only see files that you store in your (external storage)sdcard by going in mnt->sdcard->data. not in internal storage.

Comment: Have you wrote the code to store files in sdcard/ internal storage?

Comment: And also not forget to specify permission in manifest file. Please see edited code

Comment: please see edited ans to see permissions. if you forget to specify permission, than, storing code won't work in your app and won't create any folder also

Comment: Since I'm using sensor data, I can't use an emulator.

Comment: And I'm using the Internal Storage. I don't think permission to write is a problem because I'm performing a read operation as well and that works fine. However, I'm not able to locate that particular file.

Comment: As I have wrote in answer, to view internal storage file your phone must be root, you can not see it in your phone as galaxy s3 is not root by vendor. To locate your files in your phone, you can write it to external storage as internal is not accessible for your phone as it is not a root phone

Comment: If you want your files, you can read them by code and store it in external storage and then, locate that file

Comment: data/data/com.package indicates internal memory and only be accessible if phone is root

Comment: data/mnt/sdcard/com.package indicates external storage which can be accessible in your phone

Comment: Are you clear with internal and external storage and its accessibility?

Comment: I think so. I can write and read from either internal or external storage through an app. But to actually access the text file from my file explorer, I need to go for external storage or root my phone for internal storage.

Comment: "unless you are not expert enough" should be "unless you are expert enough", but I cannot edit it, as edits need to be a minimum of 6 characters.

Answer (score 8):

Do the following to be able to see your data stored in the phone's internal memory.

1. Turn on USB Debugging on your phone.
2. Connect your phone to the system.
3. Open **DDMS** perspective in your **Eclipse**.
4. Select your device from the **devices** tab on the left.
5. On the right, the last tab will be **File Explorer**. Open that.
6. Traverse to `data/data/your.app.package` to find the data you want to see.

**P.S:-** *NEVER* root your phone, unless you're a developer who loves to mess around with the `System` apps.

Comment: Firstly thanks for this. I didn't about file explorer. But I still can't access it. When I press the arrow next to data/, it just disappears. Is it because of permission?( under the field called permission, it reads drwxrwx--x).

Comment: I really doubt that. Even if its a read only permission, you can atleast be able to see it. Only if the folder is empty, it'll disappear. Also make sure that there are no loose connections and your device has the status **online**.

Comment: The phone it online. But the same thing happens whether it is external or internal storage. This answer taught me something though. Wish it worked. Thanks anyway!